# How to get rid of white border around div?

Tags: html, css

Not sure if this is padding or what...Need to get rid of that lil white border.  btw this code is included in a master table.

[image]

```
  <tr>
    <th>
    <span onclick="toggleDiv('favorites', 'favImg')" style="cursor: hand;">Favorites&nbsp;<img name="favImg" src="../images/minus.gif" /></span>
    </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div class="det" id="favorites">

    <table class="det" >
    <tr>
    <td>
        <fieldset class="det" style="padding:25;">
        <legend>Favorites</legend>
        <br/>
            <input type="radio" name="favRadio" value="public" onclick="choiceToggle('public');"/>Public:&nbsp;<select size="1" id="pubFav" name="pubFav" disabled>
                        <option selected value="">&nbsp;</option>
                        <c:forEach var="fav" items="${pubFavorites}">
                            <option value="${fav.id}">${fav.description}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                   </select>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" name="favRadio" value="user" onclick="choiceToggle('user');"/>User:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select size="1" id="userFav" name="userFav" disabled>
                        <option selected value="">&nbsp;</option>
                        <c:forEach var="fav" items="${userFavorites}">
                            <option value="${fav.id}">${fav.description}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                 </select>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" name="favRadio" value="custom" checked onclick="choiceToggle('custom');"/>Custom&nbsp;
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="det">
        <legend>Favorite Management Options</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="fav_choice" id="fav_choice" style="display:none;" value=""/>

            <input type="radio" name="fav_choice" id="fav_choice" value="rem_fav"/>Remove Favorite:&nbsp;
            <select size="1" id="removeFav" name="removeFav">
                <option selected value="">&nbsp;</option>
                <option value="id1">My saved report 1</option>
                <option value="id2">Stuff for Sally</option>
            </select>
            </br></br>

            <input type="radio" name="fav_choice" id="fav_choice" value="rename_fav"/>Rename Currently Selected Favorite:&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="fav_rename" name="fav_rename" value=""/>
            </br></br>

            <input type="radio" name="fav_choice" id="fav_choice" value="updt_fav"/>Update / Overwrite Currently Selected Favorite&nbsp;
            </br></br>

            <input type="radio" name="fav_choice" id="fav_choice" value="add_fav"/>Add to Favorites&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="add_fav_name" name="add_fav_name" value=""/>
            </br></br>

            <input type="button" name="do_choice" value="Execute Choice" onClick="processFavAction();"/>
            <input type="button" name="clear_choice" value="Clear Choice" onclick="clearFavMgmt();"/>

        </fieldset>


    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

css:

```
    table.det
    {
    background-color: #FFFFDD;
     border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table.det td
    { 
     border: none; 
     background-color: #FFFFDD;
     }

     fieldset.det 
    {     
    display:block;
    float:left;

    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    border:2px solid #CCCCCC;
    background-color: #FFFFDD;

    }
     fieldset.det legend
    {
        padding:2px 5px;
        border:2px solid #CCCCCC;
        font-weight:  bold;
        background-color: #FFFFDD;
     }

   div.det
    {   
     display:block;
     background-color: #FFFFDD;
     text-align: center;
     width: 100%;

    }
```

I think that everything

Comment: Made this a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpFj6/). Using Chrome I see no white around the div. What browser was the screenshot taken with?

Comment: look at the left and right side of the div...there is a small sliver of  white

Comment: I dont c it!!.. may be i need my glasses.. oh,wait.. i dont wear glasses!!

Comment: bro...look at the left side of the border.....you dont see a thin slice of white?????????

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SpFj6/2/ please point out the black area next to the pink?!?!?!?

Comment: forget about....next question

Comment: ??? Is this all the code?  Your main element is a <tr> which should always be inside a table.  I think you missed something here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `border-style:none;` in the CSS on the element that you don't want to display a border?  Quite frankly your image is so small I can't tell what you're talking about.

Comment: look at the border.....now look at the white space inbetween the border and the tan coloring

Answer (score 0):

Your `fieldset.det` contains `border:2px solid #CCCCCC;`

You could try to delete each of the two entries temporarily or just both. Keep a backup and see if it removes the border.